# How to make a DIV wrap for content with no whitespace?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a DIV element to wrap its content despite the content not having any whitespace. The content is a nucleic acid sequence, so inserting whitespace every x-characters is possible, but I'd rather do it more elegantly if possible.

e.g.

```
 <div>TCTTGCTGCGCCTCCGCCTCCTCCTCTGCTCCGCCACCGGCTTCCTCCTCCTGAGCAGTCAGCCCGCGCGCCGGCCGGCTCCGTTATGGCGACCCGCAGCCCTGGCGTCGTGGTGAGCAGCTCGGCCTGCCGGCCCTGGCCGGTTCAGGCCCACGCGGCAGGTGGCGGCCGGGCCCTGAGGCGCGGGATCCGCAGTGCGGGCTCGGGCGGCCGGGCCCAGGGAACCCCGCAGGCGGGGGCGGCCAGTTTCCCGGGTTCGGCTTTACGTCACGCGAGGGCGGCAGGGAGGACGGAATGGCGGGGTTTGGGGTGGGTCCCTCCTCGGGGGAGCCCTGGGAAAAGAGGACTGCGTGTGGGAAGAGAAGGTGGAAATGGCGTTTTGGTTGACATGTGCCGCCTGCGAGCGTGCTGCGGGGAGGGGCCGAGGGCAGATTCGGGAATGATGGCGCGGGGTGGGGGCGTGGGGGCTTTCTCGGGAGAGGCCCTTCCCTGGAAGTTTGGGGTGCGATGGTGAGGTTCTCGGGGCACCTCTGGAGGGGCCTCGGCACGGAAAGCGACCACCTGGGAGGGCGTGTGGGGACCAGGTTTTGCCTTTAGTTTTGCACACACTGTAGTTCATCTTTATGGAGATGCTCATGGCCTCATTGAAGCCCCACTACAGCTCTGGTAGCGGTAACCATGCGTATTTGACACACGAAGGAACTAGGGAAAAGGCATTAGGTCATTTCAAGCCGAAATTCACATGTGCTAGAATCCAGATTCCATGCTGACCGATGCCCCAGGATATAGAAAATGAGAATCTGGTCCTTACCTTCAAGAACATTCTTAACCGTAATCAGCCTCTGGTATCTTAGCTCCACCCTCACTGGTTTTTTCTTGTTTGTTGAACCGGCCAAGCTGCTGGCCTCCCTCCTCAACCGTTCTGATCATGCTTGCTAAAATAGTCAAAACCCCGGCCAGTTAAATATGCTTTAGCCTGCTTTATTATGATTATTTTTGTTGTTTTGGCAATGACCTGGTTACCTGTTGTTTCTCCCACTAAAACTTTTTAAGGGCAGGAATCACCGCCGTAACTCTAGCACTTAGCACAGTA</div>
```

I need not support every browser. I'm mainly interested in Chrome, Safari and Firefox and other standards-compliant browsers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587964/wrap-text-inside-fixed-div-with-css-or-javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CSS style like this will help:

`word-wrap:break-word`

Other CSS settings that control wrapping are described [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#wrapping).

Comment: This doesn't work in all browsers. Please follow the link in the comment of David Robles for the right answers.

Comment: I'm OK with that. I don't need to support all browsers (especially not IE). For me, this is the right answer since it works in the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox and Safari (all Mac).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a "breaking zero-width space" (&#8203;), which will break the word but will be ignored when copying into, say, notepad.